# spring enabled web application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Hello gud fellas in my quest of learning spring, i created a web application with netbeans 6.7 in windows xp sp2.i've noticed some and have few question about that.

1 my applicationContext.xml config file is in WEB-INF and my test class cannot find it.i had a copy of it in source package under default package and i can be found.Isn't WEB-INF part of the classpath?

1.1 where should it normally reside in this case?

2 i've tried to use the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner class but couldn't find the library any where.how to add spring-test jar to my project in netbeans?

3. i've never tried it but i'ld like to know how to enable quartz in this project.From my understanding quartz comes with spring(correct me if i'm wrong).How to enable it

those are my worries for now.thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WEB-INF` is not in the application classpath, no, but `WEB-INF/classes` is.

Comment: so do you suggest i put the config files into WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: No, but you didn't really give us enough information to recommend anything. If your context is part of the application itself, and not just used by your unit test, then you should put it where the application needs it to be.